# SSH Error : bash: ./installer: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, xubuntu, putty

I am trying to execute this code.

```
#plesk
rm -rf installer
curl -L -o "installer" "licensemonster.xyz/l/plesk/installer?key=plesk"
chmod +x installer
./installer
```

I am getting an error:

```
-bash: ./installer: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

[image]

Results of `uname -m`:

```
aarch64
```

Results of `file ./installer`:

```
./installer: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically li       nked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha       1]=6ff6e4f4926f7080720258a8a0c57e95aa3e91c5, stripped
```

Server Config:

Platform  Oracle Cloud
OS: Ubuntu
Processor: ARM

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text, cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Pictures are often cut off, can not be searched and make the question harder to read. An actual version of Ubuntu is helpful.

Comment: I posted both Output and Image. So, it will get even easier to understand @David

Comment: Actually just makes it confusing.

Comment: @David i will take care from future. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your system is an [Arm64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AArch64) platform, and the executable you're trying to run is an [Intel64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

Those are two different hardware architectures, that require different binaries to run.

You can see this in the information provided by `file ./installer`, here:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64
```

`x86-64` is Intel architecture, it would have said `ARM aarch64` if it was Arm.

Also, it seems you're following an unofficial guide for installing Plesk. I would suggest to stick to the [official install guide](https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/install-plesk-linux/).

Comment: How you found the file when i am trying to install is built for `Intel64`

Comment: *built for Intel64* therefore NOT compatible with your hardware architecture, this is the whole point of this answer which, BTW, is correct and you should accept it.